# memory warning issues in my cocos2d game

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

There is a memory warning issues in my game it contains many images it is aARC project but in ios 9 it doesn't release the memory.so how can i release or deallocate the memory forcely.

Comment: The exact details of doing that would truly depend on which version os cocos2d you are using ... early version 3 had issues. In all cases, look for methods (CCDirector) that suggesting clearing caches and stuff. You would not be too far from releasing unused textures and reclaiming stuff (animations, textures, sprite frame cache etc ... )